# What is Core Erlang's `letrec` for?

Tags: erlang

What is Core Erlang's `letrec` for?

Richard Carlsson writes, in ["Introduction to Core Erlang"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.6798&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> Furthermore `letrec` expressions allow local (recursive) function definitions, which ERLANG itself does not have, but which are often useful in transformations.

What transformations is letrec useful for?

Does `erlc` actually generate `letrec` when translating from Erlang? Or would `letrec`s only be generated when translating from a non-Erlang source language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Nowadays, list comprehensions are translated to letrecs
> (which are available in Core Erlang), and the letrecs are in
> turn translated to ordinary recursive functions.](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-March/050102.html)

Note that "Nowadays" is 2010. Also, there are some examples of its use in [EEP 52: Allow key and size expressions in map and binary matching](http://erlang.org/eeps/eep-0052.md):

> In OTP 23, all variables used in a segment size expression must be already
> bound in the enclosing environment.  The previous example must be rewritten
> like this using nested cases:
>
> ```
>    'foo'/1 =
>        fun (_0) ->
>              case _0 of
>                  <#{#<Sz>(16,1,'integer',['unsigned'|['big']]),
>                   #<_2>('all',1,'binary',['unsigned'|['big']])}#> when 'true' ->
>                      case _2 of
>                         <#{#<X>(Sz,1,'integer',['unsigned'|['big']])}#> when 'true' ->
>                             X
>                         <_3> when 'true' ->
>                             %% Raise function_clause exception.
>                             .
>                             .
>                             .
>                        end
>                   <_4> when 'true' ->
>                        %% Raise function_clause exception.
>                        .
>                        .
>                        .
>                  end
> ```
>
> However, as can be seen from the example, the code for raising the `function_clause`
> exception has been duplicated.  The code duplication is no big deal in this simple
> example, but it would be in a function where the binary matching clause was followed
> by many other clauses.  To avoid the code duplication, we must use `letrec` with
> the `letrec_goto` annotation:
>
> ```
>    'foo'/1 =
>        fun (_0) ->
>            ( letrec
>                  'label^0'/0 =
>                      fun () ->
>                            case _0 of
>                              <_1> when 'true' ->
>                                    %% Raise function_clause exception.
>                                    .
>                                    .
>                                    .
>                            end
>              in  case _0 of
>                    <#{#<Sz>(16,1,'integer',['unsigned'|['big']]),
>                       #<_2>('all',1,'binary',['unsigned'|['big']])}#> when 'true' ->
>                        case _2 of
>                          <#{#<X>(Sz,1,'integer',['unsigned'|['big']])}#> when 'true' ->
>                              X
>                          <_3> when 'true' ->
>                                apply 'label^0'/0()
>                        end
>                    <_4> when 'true' ->
>                          apply 'label^0'/0()
>                  end
>              -| ['letrec_goto'] )
> ```

Comment: I also just saw that `receive` is now lowered to `letrec` and primops: https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/82645f41a29b9af18cddac0b338dd2c856eb09a1

Comment: The EEP 52 link covers that as well.